# PHP IPN script works with IPN simulator but not with PayPal button

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-buttons

I have set PayPal sandbox account and created a button and put it in HTML. When I test everything out with IPN simulator it works just fine, but when purchase is made through PayPal button (sandbox mode) nothing happens. 
Here is the button code

```
<form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="NC4M3RU83QEDG">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

And here is the ipn script (works fine with ipn simulator)

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "cmd=_notify-validate&" . http_build_query($_POST));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($response == "VERIFIED") {
    $to = 'something@hotmail.com';
    $subject = 'Something';
    $headers = 'From:noreply@something.com' . "\r\n";
    $message = 'bla bla bla';
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

I have enabled IPN in my acc and I have set notify url correctly
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Elaborate on 'nothing happens'.  Check your sandbox account's IPN history: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Add logging to your IPN script. Is it receiving messages from PayPal? Log each message received. Is it able to attempt to verify them? What is the response when attempting to verify them?

Comment: I checked IPN history and it seems it is not making calls.

Comment: Seems to be an interruption in the IPN delivery service. It happens. IPN is not very reliable. This is a very old technology stack you're using, there are much better ways to integrate.